# Ordenar por fecha un array de archivos

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño script PHP para visualizar los archivos de carpetas en el servidor, pero primero necesito ordenar los archivos por los más recientes y no sé dónde colocar el asort en el código a continuación:

```
if($folder) {
   if(strstr($folder,'..')) exit(ERROR_MESAGE);
       $dir = @opendir('./'.$folder);
   } else {
       $dir = @opendir('./');
   } 

   while($file = @readdir($dir)) {
      if($file != '.' && $file != 'Índex.php' && $file != '.htaccess' && $file != 'css' &&$file !='.nomedia') {
          if($con < $n) {
             $con++; 
             continue;
          }

   if($sok < FILES_ON_PAGE) {
       $name = $file;
       $er = strrchr($name,'.');
       if(file_exists($folder.'/in.html')) 
           require_once($folder.'/in.html');
       if(file_exists($folder.'/1.txt')) 
           require_once($folder.'/1.txt');
       if($folder) {
           $sz = filesize($folder.'/'.$file);
           $file = $folder.'/'.$file;
       }   else  {
           $sz = filesize($file);
       }
       $fsize = round($sz/1024,1);

       if(is_file($file))           
       { `
```

Necesito pasar un `asort()` en los archivos y no encuentro la manera de conseguirlo, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el array?

Comment: Es gracioso que lo pregunte porque sospecho que no hay... mi pregunta es que define el orden también ? Será que esta fácil pasarlo por un array? Desde hace ratos estoy pesado como ordenar esos archivos

Comment: La pregunta especifica `asort()` como el método deseado, pero [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) se toma un array como parámetro y no hay ningún array en el código. La idea sería crear un array con los  archivos y entonces aplicar el método de ordenación que se quiera.

Comment: Entiendo, y si no aplico ningún Orden como esta ahorita Nativamente que define el Orden?

Comment: Ok. ¿lo que quieres es que cuando se lean sea directamente ordenados de más reciente a más antiguo?

Comment: Seria lo Ideal en este Caso porque Nada mas necesito que se ordene Del Archivo mas Nuevo  y exacto como dices tu que sea directamente :) será que se puede ? O lo decide el server :/

Comment: Según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), al utilizar `readdir` los archivos se devuelven en el mismo orden en el que estén en el sistema

Comment: Estuve leyendo la documentación y tienes razón.  Lo peor que no veo algún método para ordenar los archivos. Que me sugieres hacer en este caso amigo? Su opinion es de importancia y si hay ejemplo me servirla mucho

Comment: Una opción sería crear un array con la información que necesites de los archivos (en objetos de una clase propia), ordenar ese array y operar directamente sobre él en lugar de directamente con el resultado de `readdir`. Ahora escribo una respuesta con cómo se podría hacer de este modo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), al utilizar `readdir` los archivos se devuelven en el mismo orden en el que estén en el sistema (que podría ser cualquier cosa desde la fecha de creación al orden alfabético) y no se puede controlar ese orden a priori.

Una opción sería crear un array con la información que necesites de los archivos (al menos el nombre que es lo que se utiliza en el código de arriba, más la fecha que se usará para la ordenación), entonces ordenar ese array y operar con él en lugar de directamente con el resultado de `readdir`.

Para ello necesitarías:

- Declarar una clase para los archivos, por ejemplo:

  ```
  class MiArchivo {
      public $nombre = "";
      public $fecha = 0;
      function __construct($nombre, $fecha) {
          $this->nombre = $nombre;
          $this->fecha  = $fecha;
      }
  }
  ```
- Crear un array vacío donde se pondrán los archivos:

  ```
  $misarchivos = array();
  ```
- Crear una función de comparación que se usara con `usort` para ordenar el array de objetos:

  ```
  function comparaMiArchivo($a, $b) {
      return $a->fecha < $b->fecha;
  }
  ```

Teniendo eso en cuenta, los pasos a seguir serían los siguientes:

1. Define la clase (ej: `MiArchivo`)
2. Define la función de comparación (ej: `comparaMiArchivo()`)
3. Declara el array que contendrá la información de los archivos (ej: `$misarchivos`)
4. Mientras haya archivos usando `readdir`

   1. Lee el archivo y su fecha de modificación (usando [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php))
   2. Crea un objeto de la clase `MiArchivo`
   3. Insértalo en el array declarado en el paso 3
5. Ordena el array usando `usort` y la función de comparación definida en el paso 2
6. Atraviesa el array aplicando el mismo código que tenías, sólo que ahora en lugar de `$file` necesitarías algo como `$misarchivos[x]->nombre`.

El código sería algo como esto:

```
class MiArchivo {
    public $nombre = "";
    public $fecha = 0;

    function __construct($nombre, $fecha) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->fecha  = $fecha;
    }
}

function comparaMiArchivo($a, $b) {
    return $a->fecha < $b->fecha;
}

$misarchivos = array();

if($folder) {
    if(strstr($folder,'..')) exit(ERROR_MESAGE);
    $dir = @opendir('./'.$folder);
} else {
    $dir = @opendir('./');
} 

while($file = @readdir($dir)) {
    array_push($misarchivos, new MiArchivo($file, filemtime($folder ."./" . $file)));
}

usort($misarchivos, "comparaMiArchivo");

// a partir de aquí el array de archivos está ordenado de más reciente a más antiguo

foreach($misarchivos as $file) {

    // el mismo código que tenías, pero en lugar de $file sería $file->nombre
    if($file->nombre != '.' && $file->nombre != 'Índex.php' && $file->nombre != '.htaccess' && $file->nombre != 'css' &&$file->nombre !='.nomedia') {
        if($con < $n) {
            $con++; 
            continue;
         }

         ....
```

Comment: No me quede nada mas que decir..... Eres un dios En Programación . FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE . GRACIAS INFINITAS echo gracias; :D

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
<?php
//Directorio a listar
$path = './pdf';
//Abre un enlace al directorio
$dir = opendir($path);
//Iteramos el directorio
while($file=readdir($dir)){
    if(!is_dir($file)){
        //Guardamos en un array el archivo y la fecha del mismo
        $data[] = array($file, date("Y-m-d H:i:s",filemtime($path.'/'.$file)));
        //obtenemos las fechas de cada archivo, que sirven para ordenar el array anterior con la funcion array_multisort
        $dates[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",filemtime($path.'/'.$file));
    }
}
//cerramos el enlace al directorio
closedir($dir);
//ordenamos el array data según las fechas almacenadas en $dates
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $data);

//Mostramos el resultado despues de ordenar
echo "<pre>";
echo "Arreglo de fechas para ordenar";
echo "<br/>";
print_r($dates);

echo "Archivos ordenados";
echo "<br/>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Excelente Ya tengo Otro Método Muchas Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo obtendria los archivos con la funcion `glob()` esta funcion guarda los archivos en un `array` incluso tambien guarda el tamaño y la ultima fecha de modificacion de cada uno, y al estar en un `array` podrias hacer el `asort()` ya sea por la fecha, tamaño o nombre.

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda si pudieses proveer una implementación del algoritmo que describes. Considera que esta publicación no es solo para el autor, sino para la posteridad y futuros lectores que visiten esta pregunta y sus respuestas.